# SSIS recordset destination not working for time column

Tags: ssis, oledb

I am trying to store result set of OLE DB Source into SSIS object variable

[image]

In input columns tab of editor of record set destination I am getting below error for the component

[image]

The datatype of the column **Time__c** is **Time** in SQL server

[image]

Why error coming and is Time datatype not supported by recordset destination?

Comment: You properbly need to cast it to a string first in a derived column.

Comment: You can also cast it to DT_DBTIME instead in a derived column since its hh;mm;ss and your scale is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this:

Only test2 doesnt work cause its a DT_DBTIME2 - The others works. If that is how your data looks like:

**Dervied Column**
[image]

**Output**
[image]